# C Programming - Read specific line from text file

Tags: c, file-io

Here is the [code](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3b0b):

```
int main()
{
    struct vinnaren
    {
        char vinnare[20];
        int artal;
    };
    struct vinnaren v[10];
    int inputrader;
    int antalrader;  //I want antalrader to be equal to the first 
                     //line in test.txt(the first line is "5")
    char file_name[256] = "test.txt";
    char buf[512];
    FILE *f = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (!f)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f))
    {

        printf("%s", buf);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

This is the code I have. I want to make it so that 
antalrader = line1 in the file test.txt
How do I read a specific line from the file?

Comment: You count which line you've just read, and when you get to the interesting one, you keep it, or process it.

Comment: There's another (faster) solution than my answer if every line has a fixed amount of characters, I can add it to my answer if you want?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With this code you can read a file line by line and hence read a specific line from the text file:

```
lineNumber = x;

static const char filename[] = "file.txt";
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
int count = 0;
if ( file != NULL )
{
    char line[256]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line */
    {
        if (count == lineNumber)
        {
            //use line or in a function return it
            //in case of a return first close the file with "fclose(file);"
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
else
{
    //file doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: +1: Stylistically, don't separate a `++` from its variable by a space (`count++` not `count ++`).  Likewise, the subscript of an array should be firmly attached to what it is subscripting (`char line[256];` rather than `char line [ 256 ];`.  In general, I prefer no spaces within the subscript, but that's more negotiable.

Comment: Taken into account. I do this to make it look like count +1. I get it though, it's like the famous while( x --> 0) joke. Will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I got a really simple answer but I don't know if it is helping anyone:

```
int OpenCommand(int idOfCommand)
{
    fscanf(file_ptr, "%[^idOfCommand]",a[idOfCommand]);
    printf("%d\n", a[idOfCommand]);
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```